# Python offset in loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, generator, ordereddictionary

I have a piece of code which calculates the amortisation profile of a loan, and allows for defaults (cdr = constant default rate) and prepayments (cpr = constant prepayment rate).

I would also like to include recoveries, but this recoveries should be received in a future period. In the below example I am applying a 3% cdr, and I would like 60% of the defaulted loan balance to be recovered six months later.
I am struggling with this as in each loop it would need to refer back to a previous period.

On way to  solve this by first creating a table / dataframe without recoveries, and then at a second stage apply the recoveries by adding 60% of the defaults in the column recoveries, offset by 6 months.

However I am hoping there is a better / cleaner way of doing this inside the amortize function.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from collections import OrderedDict
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

def amortize(principal, int_rate,periods, cpr, cdr, date, recovery_rate, recovery_timing):
    p = 0
    beg_balance = principal
    end_balance = principal

    while end_balance > 1:
        default = round((1-(1-cdr/100)**(1/12)) * beg_balance,2)
        interest = round((int_rate/12)*max(beg_balance-default,0),2)        
        if p < periods:
            pmt = -round(np.pmt(int_rate/12, periods -p, 
                                beg_balance - default),2)
        else:
            pmt = 0
        principal = pmt - interest
        prepay = round((1-(1-cpr/100)**(1/12)) * (beg_balance - principal),2)

        end_balance = max(beg_balance - principal - prepay - default,0)
        recovery = default * recovery_rate/100

        total_cash = pmt + prepay + recovery #plus a recovery lag
        yield OrderedDict([('Period',p+1),
                          ('Month', date),
                          ('Begin_Bal', beg_balance),
                          ('Default',default),
                          ('Sched Princ',principal),
                          ('Prepay Princ',prepay),
                          ('Interest',interest),
                          ('Recovery',recovery),
                          ('Total CF',total_cash),
                          ('End Balance', end_balance)])
        p += 1
        date += relativedelta(months=1)
        beg_balance = end_balance


table = amortize(300000,0.03,360,10,3,date(2017,12,11),60,6)                            

pd.DataFrame(table).head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution sounds clean. You can also create a list of past defaults with `defaults.append(..)` then refer to `defaults[-6]`

If the loan term is very long, you can use `collections.deque` with a fixed capacity of 6 instead of a list to avoid keeping excessive old calculations.

Comment: Thank you, simple and effective!